# Make embedded jwplayer video autoplay

Tags: video, web, embed, jwplayer

I am hoping my question is simple. How do I get this video to autoplay?

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe src="myurl&amp;quality=flv" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></p>
```

Thank you!

EDIT: it is a jwplayer video

Comment: It did not unfortunately

Comment: Where is this single line embed coming from? It doesn't look like you are actually using JW Player.

Comment: You found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should activate autostart feature in jwplayer. Instead of using iframe use a div with id and then configure the features with js in a short script. 
Example:

```
<div id="myVideo"></div>

<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myVideo");
    playerInstance.setup({
      file: "/videoURL/video.mp4",
      width: 560,
      height: 315,
      autostart: true
    });
</script>
```

if you need to mute the video at autostart then just add mute: true
To get more info you can check here: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

If you are using youtube there is an autoplay parameter

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="[YouTube Video URL]?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: It's not unfortunately :/